# How would you translate “playing with prime numbers” into Latin?

Tags: english-to-latin-translation, mathematics

I'm building a website about prime numbers, and I want to put the following  sentence: "playing with prime numbers" in Latin in the subtitle of the main page. Google Translate translation is: "ludens primum cum numero", but I'm not sure if it is correct. I guess it should be:"ludens cum prima numeri" .

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If, as I believe, the sentence stands as the theme of the website you should use the infinitive *ludere* instead of the participle *ludens*. The latter means "who plays/is playing".

As for "with prime numbers", it is an adverb of means and in Latin (for inanimate objects)  this is expressed by the simple ablative, which gives *numeris primis*.

All in all: ***Numeris primis ludere***. Note that in principle you could put *ludere* first, but this seems more natural.

Comment: Is "primis" the correct adjective in Latin, though?  After all, its primary meaning is "first", so it's at best ambiguous.  I'd prefer an adjective meaning "irreducible".

Comment: @CMonsour: It is the one which has been historically used. Euler wrote [_De Numeris Primis valde Magnis_](http://eulerarchive.maa.org//docs/originals/E283.pdf) for example.

Comment: On the other hand, I just verified that Gauss used "primis", so I guess that is best after all.

Comment: @CMonsour: Yes, as I said: Gauss, Euler and every other mathematician who wrote about primes in Latin.

Comment: what do you mean with "adverb of means"?

Comment: @fdb: Should it have been "adverb of instrument"? I meant a part of speech that expresses by what means, "how" in the sense of "with/by/thanks to what", the action is completed.

Comment: @Vincenzo Oliva: Is "ludere" here a hanging infinitive? There is no subject answering the question who or what. Who is playing with prime numbers?  Should it be "we play" or "let's play"?

Comment: @tony: It _is_ a hanging infinitive, and the action _itself_ of playing is the subject - the corresponding verb is simply implied. Just like you can think of the subtitle "Playing with prime numbers" as a truncation of "The theme of this website is _playing with prime numbers_".